# How to select this element using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing some third-party web software for my company. It returns some html which I can't directly change. I'd like to make some minor updates using jQuery but am not familiar with this syntax.

```
<div c:id="container"> </div>
```

How do I find this div in the dom using jQuery? What is "c:id" anyway? I've never seen that syntax before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c:id` is just an html attribute like any other. You can access it in jQuery using the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
var container = $('[c\\:id="container"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the entire XML ?
It probably is an XML namespace define with **xmlns:c={url}**

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
var el = $('div[c\\:id="container"]');
```

(unescaped `:` being a pseudo-class)

Comment: I thought about this when I answered, you sure colon needs to be escaped as it is an attribute selector?

Comment: @Xander it doesn't seem to work for me when unescaped http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/mytDG/

Comment: yeah, you're right - would've tested myself if I wasn't on my cell phone :P